# How do I plot only the time portion of a timestamp including a date?

Tags: r, timestamp, strptime, ggplot2

So I have a set of timestamps like this:

```
datetime<-c("2011-09-28 03:33:00", "2011-08-24 13:41:00", "2011-09-19 16:14:00", "2011-08-18 11:01:00", "2011-09-17 06:35:00", "2011-08-15 12:48:00")
```

I want to make a histogram of only the times. What I did was to split the column at the space to get only the times, then convert back to a POSIXct object in order for qplot to plot it:

```
library(ggplot2, stringr)    
qplot(as.POSIXct(strptime((str_split_fixed(as.character(time), " ", 2)[,2]), "%H:%M:%S")))
```

However, the output of `as.POSIXct(strptime((str_split_fixed(as.character(datetime), " ", 2)[,2]), "%H:%M:%S"))` is

```
"2011-10-04 03:33:00 PDT" "2011-10-04 13:41:00 PDT" "2011-10-04 16:14:00 PDT" "2011-10-04 11:01:00 PDT" "2011-10-04 06:35:00 PDT" "2011-10-04 12:48:00 PDT"
```

qplot plots what I want, but this seems like a convoluted hack to me. Surely there's a better way to do this? I could convert into epoch time and plot that, but I was trying to avoid having to do that as an extra step.

The larger question is, "How do I control the output of strptime?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
require("ggplot2")
dtstring <- c(
  "2011-09-28 03:33:00", "2011-08-24 13:41:00", "2011-09-19 16:14:00",
  "2011-08-18 11:01:00", "2011-09-17 06:35:00", "2011-08-15 12:48:00"
)
dtPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(dtstring)

# extract time of 'date+time' (POSIXct) in hours as numeric
dtTime <- as.numeric(dtPOSIXct - trunc(dtPOSIXct, "days"))

p <- qplot(dtTime) + xlab("Time slot") + scale_x_datetime(format = "%S:00")
print(p)
```

The calculation, `dtPOSIXct - trunc(dtPOSIXct, "days")`, extracts time of POSIXct class objects in hours.

[image: plot(p)]

For `ggplot2-0.9.1`:

```
require("ggplot2")
require("scales")
dtstring <- c(
  "2011-09-28 03:33:00", "2011-08-24 13:41:00", "2011-09-19 16:14:00",
  "2011-08-18 11:01:00", "2011-09-17 06:35:00", "2011-08-15 12:48:00"
)
dtPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(dtstring)

# extract time of 'date+time' (POSIXct) in hours as numeric
dtTime <- as.numeric(dtPOSIXct - trunc(dtPOSIXct, "days"))

p <- qplot(dtTime) + xlab("Time slot") +
     scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%S:00"))
print(p)
```

For `ggplot2-0.9.3.1`:

```
require("ggplot2")
require("scales")
dtstring <- c(
  "2011-09-28 03:33:00", "2011-08-24 13:41:00", "2011-09-19 16:14:00",
  "2011-08-18 11:01:00", "2011-09-17 06:35:00", "2011-08-15 12:48:00"
)
dtPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(dtstring)

# extract time of 'date+time' (POSIXct) in hours as numeric
dtTime <- as.numeric(dtPOSIXct - trunc(dtPOSIXct, "days"))
class(dtTime) <- "POSIXct"

p <- qplot(dtTime) + xlab("Time slot") +
     scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%S:00"))
print(p)
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used trunc that much. There's always something new to learn!

Comment: I'm confused about something. I'm working with a similar situation albeit with just over 2 million observations. When I use **format = "%S:00"**, I just get 00:00 for all X axis labels. I tried changing to **%H** (S = seconds and H = hours for this function), and that's not right, either: the X axis starts at 17:00, counts up to 0:00 then back to 18:00 at the end. (The labels are evenly spaced over that 25 hour span.)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this has something to do with that I am in CDT, which is 5 hours behind GMT, and POSIX time starts counting from midnight GMT, Jan. 1, 1970? So if I add 5 * 60 * 60 to each value...

No, scratch that. I am in CST right now, which is GMT-6.

Comment: -1 not sure how you got this, but I can't reproduce this result. as mentioned by @ArenCambre, all x axis labels are 00:00

Comment: I wrote this post (Oct 5 '11).  The `ggplot2` package have been updated.  For `ggplot2-0.9.1`, please try to add, `require("scales")`, and change `format = "%S:00"` to `labels = date_format("%S:00")`.

Comment: @Triadsou. I tried to follow the same approach but I get the following error "Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only".

Comment: @Jdbaba `ggplot2-0.9.3.1` probably uses strict type checking.  Please follow the new example code.

Comment: Version for `0.9.3.1` also works for `ggplot2_2.1.0` : ) thanks

Comment: @Triadsou. i get same error  all x axis values are 0.00 although point are evenly spaced on x-axis.i have used librray scales and labels = date_format("%S:00") but still error persists

Answer (score 4):

Just use the basic tools as they were intended:

```
dtstring <- c("2011-09-28 03:33:00", "2011-08-24 13:41:00", "2011-09-19 16:14:00", "2011-08-18 11:01:00", "2011-09-17 06:35:00", "2011-08-15 12:48:00")
datetime <- as.POSIXct(dtstring)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(datetime)
```

The format of your strings is the default for parsing with `as.POSIXct`, see `?strptime` for details or if you have something other than this format.

If you want a specific string format from your date-time values, use `format`, as in

```
format(datetime, "%d-%b")
[1] "28-Sep" "24-Aug" "19-Sep" "18-Aug" "17-Sep" "15-Aug"
```

Again, see `?strptime` for details. If you really want to trash the time values, you can use the `Date` class.  Just be aware that date-times or dates need their full structure, any other representation is just formatted text.

qplot(as.Date(datetime))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that plots the timestamps, not just the time portion. I'm actually looking to strip the dates off and just plot the times, so the x axis would span only 24 hours.

Comment: Which keyword argument does your `"%d-%b"` variable correspond to in the `format` call? I can't find anything that would be appropriate to it in `?format`.