# R: converting POSIXct to minutes

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- data_frame(
time= c("1899-12-31 02:21:00 UTC", "1899-12-31 05:56:00 UTC"),
number = c(1, 2))
```

I would like to be able to covert the time variable to be in minutes in a new column so that the dataframe looks like this:

```
d1 <- data_frame(
time= c("1899-12-31 02:21:00 UTC", "1899-12-31 05:56:00 UTC"),
number = c(1, 2),
minutes = c("141", "356"))
```

I can do this using `lubridate` if my time variable is `02:21:00` and `05:56:00` however when I'm using `read_excel()` to load in the data it's turning my variable into `POSIXct`, eg `1899-12-31 02:21:00 UTC` and `1899-12-31 05:56:00 UTC` which is making it hard to convert.

I need to use `read_excel()` to read the data in so it's not an option to convert to a .csv and do it that way (which would stop it reading it as a `POSIXct`).

Comment: Are you using a special form of `data_frame`? Or just a typo?

Comment: Apologies - have updated with the library

Comment: Do you mean `library(lubridate); mutate(d1, minutes = hour(time) * 60 + minute(time))` ?

Comment: Yeah that's it actually. I think I might delete this actually as I think there was an issue with the library not updating and this not working previous to posting. Unless you think it's worth leaving up @markus

Comment: Don't delete it. It might help others in the future. Found a possible dupe. [Still, don't delete it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract hours and seconds from POSIXct for plotting purposes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705328/extract-hours-and-seconds-from-posixct-for-plotting-purposes-in-r)