# How to extract hour from datetime column in R

Tags: r

Can anyone help a beginner please? When I use this code:

`biketimes2$time <- format(as.Date(biketimes2$started_at),"%H")`

to extract the hour from the 'started_at' dttm column in the dataset named 'biketimes2', I just get a character column of zeroes (I called it 'time'). What should I do to get the hours, eg 23, 08, 18? You can't see it here but the time section of 'started_at' is greyed out in the tibble.

Here's the result:

```
 head(biketimes2)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  started_at          date       month day_of_week days  time 
  <dttm>              <date>     <chr> <chr>       <chr> <chr>
1 2022-05-23 23:06:58 2022-05-23 05    Monday      23    00   
2 2022-05-11 08:53:28 2022-05-11 05    Wednesday   11    00   
3 2022-05-26 18:36:28 2022-05-26 05    Thursday    26    00   
4 2022-05-10 07:30:07 2022-05-10 05    Tuesday     10    00   
5 2022-05-10 17:31:56 2022-05-10 05    Tuesday     10    00   
6 2022-05-04 14:48:55 2022-05-04 05    Wednesday   04    00   
>
```

I tried searching for a solution, here and elsewhere.

Comment: What exactly did you try when you searched for a solution? A [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=extract+hour+from+datetime+r)  shows plenty of approaches, as does this question: [extract hours and seconds from POSIXct for plotting purposes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705328/extract-hours-and-seconds-from-posixct-for-plotting-purposes-in-r)

Comment: Why are you using `as.Date()`? When you convert from a _timestamp_ to a _date_, it by-definition removes the "hour" part of the timestamp (as well as minutes and seconds). Did you try just `format(biketimes2$started_at,"%H")`?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, since the code is correct but the conversion to `Date`-class is the reason why it returns `"00"`.

Comment: (Side note: `format` methods exist for many different classes of objects, and frustratingly for many of them the second argument is _not_ `format=` to which you are implicitly assigning `"%H"`. It works here just fine, and you'll see lots of code snippets here on SO continue to suggest that, but when dealing with a function like this with varying arguments, it is usually a safe thing to name that argument, as in `format(biketimes2$started_at, format="%H")`. Just some defensive programming with that function. Good luck!)

Comment: Thanks both for your help + teaching, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lubridate is your friend here. it looks like the started_at column is a datetime object already. You can try this:

```
biketimes2$time <- lubridate::hour(biketimes2$started_at)
```